# Python requests and JavaScript

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a [German bank account](https://www.berliner-volksbank.de/banking-private/entry) to get account statements automatically.

I am doing this with [Kenneth Reitz' excellent `requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

I can do GET and POST requests. Everything works fine. But if I try to login (via POST request) the site says it wants JavaScript turned on.

Is there a workaround? Or do I need to switch to PhantomJS or Selenium? (Unfortunately I could not make PhantomJS work with `Cheerio` (the JS equivalent of BeautifulSoup).

---

EDIT

[Here](https://www.berliner-volksbank.de/banking-privatedemo/entry) is a demo login for that bank account. User: 1008800049 and pin: 11113 (and if needed: rzbk=0120)

Comment: it is very likely that the message is always being returned by the main request, and later javascript rendering removes that tag from the DOM or just hides it. You can replicate the requests yourself (that javascript doesn't really matter), but for that, you'll have to deep more into the functionality of the site and how requests are being made there.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. I can replicate that by disabling JS in Firefox and trying to log in. If tells me JS is needed. And offers me the login form again.

Comment: (1) In a browser, open developer tools, network tab, and see what data exchange happens when a normal login is done. There can be surprises, like AJAX calls or JS client-side encryption. (2) Some banks offer API and access tokens, it's more convenient than scraping HTML.

Comment: In Germany there is no Bank that offers an API access. Surprising and sad